# How to Increase file size of Importing Products to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, file-permissions, varien-file-uploader, core-file-storage

I'm looking to import product into M2 but the allowed size is 2MB and my file has 2.33 MB how can I increase the size?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the upload size in your php.ini file.

Locate `upload_max_filesize` and increase its value

```
upload_max_filesize = 5MB
```

Restart the Mysql and Apache server for the changes to take effect.

If this doesn't work please also note that the value of `max_allowed_packet` must be 1.5 times greater than the size of your import CSV file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked but now got another error

Comment: Please post the issue error and screen shots

Comment: here it's http://prntscr.com/ntjvpg

Comment: The column names in CSV file is invalid, try downloading the sample CSV file and format the data to be imported according to the sample data CSV file

Comment: Where do I get that sample CSV I'm trying to download it from M2 and it's not working

Comment: Found it let me try this way. Thank you so much @raj Mohan R

Comment: Also, need to increase post_max_size